# Custom raw html

Tags: html, wordpress

I use codecolorer wp plugin to show raw html codes. But my problem is that I can not customize the codes inside. For example, I would like to make some words in bold. Also, i can not colour the codes exactly as I would like (each code individually).

Do someone know how to customize choosen codes within the raw table or tell me another wp plugin which let us customize each codes?

I could do it by myself without any plugin, just to change ">" and "<" with html names but i have a code which includes both types <, > and `&quot;` of codes:

```
<span class='post-comment-link'>
<b:if cond='data:post.hasJumpLink'>
<a expr:href='data:post.url + &quot;#more&quot;' expr:title='data:post.title'><data:post.jumpText/></a> |
</b:if>
...
```

What Stackoverflow uses here for the raw html codes (codes between apostrophes) would be the best solution but I did not find on internet.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i got the answer ! It is a bit complicated but essential :

1. You must go to Visual text editor
2. Paste the code as it is
3. Change to HTML editor (Text editor)
4. The > and < are changed to `&gt;` and `&lt;` and the `&quot;` is changed to `&amp;quot;` automatically.
5. Beeing already in HTML editor (Text editor), we can add codes for customize, for example to make the line bold, we add the `<b></b>` codes normally : **<a expr:href='data:post.url + &quot;#more&quot;' expr:title='data:post.title'>**

Take care NOT to swith back to Visual editor or you can start everything from the beginning !